# How to disable Qt central widget resize grip/handle/resizecursor

Tags: c++, qt

This problem might be so specific that I won't expect much help.. but still I'll try my luck. I've been battling with this problem for a long enough, going crazy with it, having no real solution after trying many different combinations of sizepolicies and resize event operations. So far this has been my best solution, while being far from ideal.

I have a mainwindow with three widgets (central is a QWidget while top and bottom are QDockWidget):

First is the central widget:

```
QSizePolicy sizepolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
central->setSizePolicy(sizepolicy);
MainWindow::setCentralWidget(central);
```

Then a bottom widget:

```
QWidget* btitle = new QWidget(this);
bottom->setTitleBarWidget(btitle);
bottom->setMinimumHeight(65);
bottom->setAllowedAreas(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea);
this->addDockWidget(Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea, bottom);
```

and a top widget:

```
QWidget* ttitle = new QWidget(this);
top->setTitleBarWidget(ttitle);
top->setMinimumHeight(30);
top->setMaximumHeight(30);
top->setAllowedAreas(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea);
this->addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, top);
```

They all align correctly without unwanted borders/closebuttons/etc, and change size correctly when the application window is resized. But just under the top widget there is a mouse cursor hotspot for central widget resize (like this on mac [sizehandle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8rnp.png)). **Software user can easily by accident grab it while operating the top widget, and start resizing the central widget. I have written an automatic position/size fixer which works fine for fixing the widget sizes/places back to normal BUT the widget size grip/handle/cursorspot is now where it was released and stays there until grabbed again and resized**. The exactly same thing happens with bottom widget, but not with top widget that has very fixed position and size. It also seems these handles work only from the top border of a widget.

this is my position/size fix implemented in mainwindow:

```
    this->bottom->setGeometry(0, this->central->height()+30, this->width(), bottomsize);
this->central->setGeometry(0, 31, this->width(), this->height() - (30+bottomsize));
```

As the code implies, the bottom widget has a dynamic height (bottomsize) and central widget adjusts it's size according to it, but the top widget has always the same size.

Also when pulling the resize grip of the widgets top border, the widget sizes jump between positions corrected by lines above and the previous mouse dragged position; On mouse move event it's the dragged position and otherwise the corrected position. Also when the grip has been dragged and released somewhere else than widgets top position, resizing the application window does the same position/size jumping thing with widget places and sizes...

So **how can I remove that resize handle/grip completely**, and if that is impossible, **why doesn't the handle change it's place according widgets SetGeometry()** that sets everything else into right places, but instead the handle position stays where it was previously released.

Thanks for reading this far, I hope you have something for this. 
I am using OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan) and Qt 5.5.

Comment: Have you tried to set the top widget in the top QDockWidget to fixed height? Try `ttitle->setFixedHeight(30);`